# Is it possible to encounter race condition when processing data with a Node.js TCP server?

Tags: node.js, tcp

I am setting up a TCP server using Node.js, and on 'data' event I pass the data to an instance of parser object which processes the data and then push to the cloud. My question is that in the event where the first on data event hasn't finished processing, but the second on 'data' event of the same TCP connection has been fired, what would happen to the data, will the second data packet be processed 'concurrently' as the first one?

This TCP server is meant to handle multiple connections and each connection is handling fairly large amount of data continuously. And It is important for the data to be processed sequentially.

```
var net = require('net');
const rfDataParser = require('./MyDataParser');
const HOST = 'localhost'
const PORT = 8000;

var server = net.createServer(onClientConnected);

function onClientConnected(sock) {
    const parser = new rfDataParser();
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        parser.parse(data);
    }
}

server.listen(PORT, HOST, function() {  
    console.log('server listening on %j', server.address());
});
```

I expect the data of the second 'data' event not get processed until the data of the first 'data' event has finished processing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're asking two different questions here,

> Will the second data packet be processed 'concurrently' as the first one?

No, the event-loop will queue up the handling of the second event if the first one is still being handled. Node.js is a single threaded platform; There's no way two lines in a JS file are executed concurrently.

> Is it possible to encounter a race condition?

Yes, while while your code runs in a single thread, node itself  relies on multiple threads to handle I/O. If your processing includes asynchronous I/O and you do not wait for a callback before calling the job done then a race condition is possible.

You can read more about the event loop [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why is that TCP requests aren't guaranteed to be received in the same order they were sent in? I thought TCP ensures that packets are arrived in order while UDP doesn't.Or is it something in Node.js that might mess up the order?

Comment: (1) There is only one question, and it is about race conditions, which have nothing to do with order of arrival. (2) TCP guarantees correct data ordering. (3) Your citation specifically says there is only one thread, backed by asynchronous I/O operations in the OS. This does not require multiple threads.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for clarifying! So can I assume Ismail's answer to concurrency is correct?

Comment: @user207421 (2) That is only true for each separate connection. Edited the answer so that would be clear. (3) All the javascript runs in one thread, however, node has a "worker pool" that has a small number of threads to handle I/O https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

Comment: @zsedcx Nothing in node will mess up the ordering, my answer wasn't clear enough. please check the updated one.

Comment: @IsmailSabry Thanks for your edited answer, it think it answered my question. So in conclusion as long as there is no shared state between connections, I can be sure that data packets for an individual connection will be received and processed in order.

Comment: @zsedcx Yes, you can.

Comment: @zsedcx Again, as long as the processing itself doesn't include any asynchronous procedures.

Comment: Rubbish. See [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793) #1.5. (2) is true *within* a connection. Otherwise TCP would be unusable and everybody would have to write sequencing code. Your claim about 'only true for separate connections' is strictly meaningless, and is contradicted by what you have edited into your answer. What separate connections have to do with the question is another mystery.

Comment: @user208421 Please read the question carefully, it states clearly that the code is meant to handle multiple connections and still process the requests sequentially. Now if client A sends two messages M1 then M2 and then a moment later client B send a message M3, it is a certainty that M1 will be processed before M2 but there will be no way to guarantee that M1 will be processed before M3.

Comment: @user207421 You were right, that has nothing to do with a race condition. I've edited my answer.